# Add a class using jquery after find a ID

Tags: jquery

i need add a class after i compared two ids them i wrote this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".tab-content .InfoUp:first" ).addClass('in active');
        $( "#InfoUpHeight .InfoUpFrom:first" ).addClass('active');
    $( '.InfoUpFrom a' ).click(function(){
        var idArray = [];
        var i = "";
        $('.InfoUp').each(function () {
            idArray.push(this.id);
        });
        var TabReview = $('.InfoUpFrom.active a i').attr('id');
        for (var i = idArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(idArray[i] == TabReview){
                $("#InfoUpHeight .InfoUpFrom:first" ).removeClass('active');
                $(".InfoUp:first" ).removeClass('in active');
                $(".InfoUp #"+idArray[i]).addClass('in active');
                $(TabReview).addClass('active');
            }
        }

    });
});
```

i test the code and found the ids but no add the class.
Thank you.

Comment: `$(".InfoUp #"+idArray[i]).addClass('in active');` adds two classes in and active. This is expected ryt

Comment: Not an answer but you can't have spaces in your class names, you'll want to change 'in active' to 'inactive'

Comment: It should be $('#' + TabReview).addClass('active');

Answer (score 1):

add '#' to jQuery selector (`$('#' + TabReview).addClass('active');`):

```
for (var i = idArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (idArray[i] === TabReview) {
    $("#InfoUpHeight .InfoUpFrom:first" ).removeClass('active');
    $(".InfoUp:first" ).removeClass('in active');
    // $(".InfoUp #" + idArray[i]).addClass('in active');
    $(".InfoUp #" + TabReview).addClass('in active');
    $('#' + TabReview).addClass('active');
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is the class no add to `$(".InfoUp #"+idArray[i]).addClass('in active');` and is where i need add it

Comment: could you create a plunker with your code? So I can check it. If not, try to debug your code: 1) is TabReview non-empty string? 2) make sure you pass if (idArray[i] === TabReview) condition, 3) check $(".InfoUp #"+idArray[i]).size() - see that you have at least one such element, 4) check $('#' + TabReview).size()

Answer (score 0):

You've already defined in the variable TabReview with the $(), if you take off the $ and () around TabReview within the for loop, your code should work.

Comment: TabReview is a string holding ID attribute value, not jQuery object